# How can I prevent java processes from stealing focus?

Tags: macos, window-manager, java

Has anyone else noticed that command line java applications in OS X create GUI processes that steal focus (ie, groovy, maven sub processes)? I'm finding it extremely annoying; probably because I've been living with it for 6-8 months since I think OS X 10.6.

How can I prevent java processes from doing this in OS X?

Comment: This is a very good question, but I think it depends on the implementation of your Java app. If you ask those guys in Stack Overflow they might now which Java flag to turn on background mode when launching.

Comment: Yeah I asked there first, and never got any kind of response. When I do 'java -version' I see: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11D50b)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eventually I found the basic solution:

For Java applications in general you can specify that they are 'headless', by adding the option `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to your java application.

(also posted to stackoverflow).

Comment: Even with this flag my invisible Android simulator steal focus.